# converting date to new format not working using strtotime()

Tags: php, date, date-format

I have date format in my database like this **'13/09/2022'** but my client suggest to change this format into this format **'09/13/2022'** so I use `strtotime()` but instead of having correct result it give this kind of result **01/01/1970** and you can see it give me wrong result. can someone explain what happen?

This is my code:

```
<?php 
$oldDate = '13/09/2022';
$newDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($oldDate)); 
echo $newDate; 
?>
```

Comment: Try this

<?php
$oldDate = '13/09/2022';
$newDate = date("m/d/Y",strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $oldDate)));
echo $newDate;

 str_replace('/', '-', $oldDate) replaces the '/' with '-' to create a format that strtotime can understand. Then, it converts the modified date to the 'mm/dd/yyyy' format using the date function.

Answer (score 0):

Your can try this:

```
echo DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '13/09/2022')->format("m/d/Y");
```

According to the documentation, 'DD/MM/YY' is not a standard format: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php.